# How to assign a viewcontroller as a self viewcontroller to the appdelegate class?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller class LoginViewcontroller where i need to add that view cotroller as a self viewcontroller to the appdelegate class. I need something like when i try to access self.viewcontroller, my LoginViewController should respond. Any help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write down this code:

AppDelegate.h File

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
```

Create Object of LoginViewController class

```
LoginViewController *loginVC;
```

Create Property of LoginViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) LoginViewController *loginVC;
```

AppDelegate.m File

```
@synthesize loginVC;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.loginVC = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is setup the root view controller for your application, then:

```
self.rootViewController = loginViewController;
```

If that's not what you need, please provide some more info as to what you´re trying to accomplish.